# How do I solve the picture puzzle involving a basement key?

Tags: indiana-jones-staff-of-kings

Early on in *Indiana Jones and the Staff of Kings* (Nintendo DS version), you have to find a basement key. You find a room with six pictures on the wall which you can press, and a magic lantern.

When you blow on the lantern, different pictures are displayed. This implies you should press the pictures in the order indicated by the lantern. This seems to be the accepted solution.

My problem is that two of the pictures shown by the lantern do not match the pictures on the wall. The wall has what looks like a chicken and a rat, and these don't appear on the lantern — two different images are displayed.

Even if I stick with the pictures that *do* match, I can only press two pictures in a row — pressing a third resets all the pictures. The lantern does repeat the same sequence all the time, but there's no clue as to the beginning image of the sequence - is it the one that's showing when you enter the room or the first that shows when you blow on the lantern?

Has anyone gotten past this? Is my game broken? Or is there some missing information that I can't see?

Answer (score 1):

According to the (now defunct) Cheatmasters forums:

> Stand in front of the lantern, blow on it, and whatever symbol appears is the picture on the wall to touch. **Some symbols are not on the wall, skip them and blow on the lantern again** until you have seen the fox, the tiger and the horse. The panel opens and the key is in it.